# Issue when splicing array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have a vue application that gets a set of objects from an external REST API.

In a component, I sort and filter the object into an array of objects based on a field called rank, like this:

```
let myResults = _.orderBy(this.search_result, 'rank', 'desc').filter(service => (service.rank >= 5) ? service: "");
```

I then need to move a single element/object to the end of the list before rendering it, however, when I tried to do this:

```
let index = myResults.findIndex(e => e.name === 'Target Element');
myResults.push(myResults.splice(index,1));
```

It didn't work; It pushed an empty element back to the list. Eventually, I got it working by doing the following:

```
myResults.push(myResults.splice(index,1)[0]);
```

I noticed the `splice` was creating an array that looked like `[object, object]` with all the target object in the zero index object.

I don't really understand why this happened. Have I done something to the original object somewhere or is this a vue thing?

Comment: Vue.js has nothing to do with it. It's a JS thing and the way Array.prototype.splice() works. Returns always an Array, of the removed items, or empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript [Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) returns an Array.

> #### [Return value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice#return_value)
>
> An **array** containing the deleted elements.
> If only one element is removed, an array of one element is returned.
> If no elements are removed, an empty array is returned.

Since an Array is returned, you're `.push()`-ing and Array into an existent array. As you noticed correctly, you need to *extract* that *one* Object using `removedItems[0]`, making

```js
myResults.push(myResults.splice(index,1)[0]);
```

or equally

```js
// Remove from array 1 item
const removedItems = myResults.splice(index, 1); // Array of removed items
// Get the first Object from array
const item = removedItems[0]; // Object
// Append one Object
myResults.push(item);
```

the correct approach.